# How do I enable/disable RRO from Java/Kotlin?

Tags: android

I found adb commands to manually enable/disable Runtime Resource Overlay (RRO) Application using `adb shell cmd overlay` shell command. But how do I do this programmatically from Java/Kotlin? Does Android provide any API to support this?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you also include your use case, probably someone can come with an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the following permission to your app `CHANGE_OVERLAY_PACKAGES`.

And then use these APIs to programmatically enable or disable:

```
OverlayManager  mOverlayManager = (OverlayManager) getSystemService(Context.OVERLAY_SERVICE);​

mOverlayManager.setEnabled(< target-package-name> ,<true/false>, new UserHandle(0));
```

Refer to Android developer [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/rros) here.